# How to populate a table with specific column datas from a union set

Tags: sql-server

What i wannt is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[UNIONTABLE1]
UNION 
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[UNIONTABLE2]
AS RESULTUNION;

DELETE FROM [dbo].[ResultTestTable];

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ResultTestTable]
  ( 
  test2
  ,test3
  ,test4
  ,test5
  ,test6
  ,test7
   )
  VALUES
  (
   RESULTUNION.LT_ALL_TAB_NAME
  ,RESULTUNION.LT_SCH_KL_RED_GASDRUCK
  ,RESULTUNION.LT_EINST_NOR_ZEIT + RESULTUNION.LT_EINST_NOR_AUSBLASZEIT
  ,RESULTUNION.LT_EINST_SAN_ZEIT + RESULTUNION.LT_EINST_SAN_AUSBLASZEIT
  ,RESULTUNION.LT_EINST_NOR_ZEIT_PCS + RESULTUNION.LT_EINST_NOR_AUSBLASZEIT_PCS
  ,RESULTUNION.LT_EINST_SAN_ZEIT_PCS + RESULTUNION.LT_EINST_SAN_AUSBLASZEIT_PCS
  );
```

I wannt to fill the ResultTestTable with all rows of the RESULTUNION table but only with specific columns of the RESULTUNION table.
And additionally i wannt to add two column datas of the RESULTUNION table and map it to one column in the ResultTestTable.
The added values are floats.

I m working with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

The statemant above does not work, which is obvious, but i dont know how to do it right.
If I execute the statement above, i get the following error:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test_storedProcedure, Line 31
The multi-part identifier "RESULTUNION.LT_ALL_TAB_NAME" could not be bound.

I assume i have to do something like a for-loop but than i dont know how much rows the RESULTUNION table has to loop over.

Does anybody has an idea.
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, never use "SELECT *" in your SQL, always specify the column names. Once you take that into account, it becomes easier to see the solution. Here it is:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ResultTestTable]
  (
  test2
  ,test3
  ,test4
  ,test5
  ,test6
  ,test7
   )
SELECT 
  LT_ALL_TAB_NAME
  ,LT_SCH_KL_RED_GASDRUCK
  ,LT_EINST_NOR_ZEIT + LT_EINST_NOR_AUSBLASZEIT
  ,LT_EINST_SAN_ZEIT + LT_EINST_SAN_AUSBLASZEIT
  ,LT_EINST_NOR_ZEIT_PCS + LT_EINST_NOR_AUSBLASZEIT_PCS
  ,LT_EINST_SAN_ZEIT_PCS + LT_EINST_SAN_AUSBLASZEIT_PCS
FROM [dbo].[UNIONTABLE1]
UNION ALL -- This will keep duplicate rows. UNION, without ALL, removes duplicates
SELECT 
  LT_ALL_TAB_NAME
  ,LT_SCH_KL_RED_GASDRUCK
  ,LT_EINST_NOR_ZEIT + LT_EINST_NOR_AUSBLASZEIT
  ,LT_EINST_SAN_ZEIT + LT_EINST_SAN_AUSBLASZEIT
  ,LT_EINST_NOR_ZEIT_PCS + LT_EINST_NOR_AUSBLASZEIT_PCS
  ,LT_EINST_SAN_ZEIT_PCS + LT_EINST_SAN_AUSBLASZEIT_PCS
ROM [dbo].[UNIONTABLE2]
```

Obviously, if the columns of the two tables have different names, you'll have to amend the query accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome. And, if you accept the answer, even more welcome! Or you can send me a bratwurst, I also like them. :)